# How to concatenate today's date and hour selected by user to insert it as a datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime, datepicker

I have a form where user enter time :

```
<form method="post" action="requetes/ajouterHeureDebutJournee.php" role="form" id="formulaire" style="padding: 35px;">
    <input type="time" id="heure" name="heure">
    <center>
      <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small btn-2" id="valider" name="valider" type="submit"></button>
    </center>
  </form>
```

I receive the value in this PHP code. I want to concatenate today's date and the hour entered by the user. Note : the parameter of the function is the hour entered by the user :

```
            function insertionHeureDebutJournee($date_commencement_journee)
            {
              if ($this->estPremiereConnexion()){
                $identifiant_camion = $this->GetID();
                $date_jour = Date('Y-m-d');
                $date_merge = new DateTime($date_jour->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $date_commencement_journee->format('H:i:s')); // This line throw an error
                $connexion = $this->GetConnexion();
                $stmt = $connexion->prepare("INSERT INTO activiteVALUES (0, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $ID, $date_merge);
                if($stmt->execute() === false){
                  echo 'Problème dans l\'insertion de la date et l\'heure de début de journée';
                }else{
                  header('Location: ../index.php');
                }
              }
            }
```

How to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: You can probably do it a lot easier, but what does `$date_commencement_journee` contain?

Comment: It's the hour entered by the user

Comment: So a whole number? Then yes, you can easily drop a few things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time elements (unless in Safari) pass in as `h:i`, so you have most of your work already done. You just need to append it to a date:

```
$date_jour = date('Y-m-d '.$date_commencement_journee.':00');
```

So if `$date_commencement_journee` is `16:00`, `$date_jour` becomes `2020-09-04 16:00:00`. You can skip the DateTime line, since it's already formatted.